# Why at Compton edge count is higher than that at zero degree angle

Tags: nuclear-physics, gamma-rays

In theoretical Compton continuum curve count is higher for Compton edge region than that at zero degree region and this difference increase with increase in incident photon energy. Now count should be proportional to Klein-Nishina differential cross-section. But the polar graph of Klein-Nishina differential cross-section formula always shows higher value at zero degree angle than at 180 angle at any energy of incident gamma photon.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify this question. A drawing would help. Where in the Compton continuum curve is the zero degree region?

Answer (score 1):

This is the differential cross section for Compton scattering.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}
\propto\left(\frac{m}{m+\omega(1-\cos\theta)}\right)^2
\left(\frac{m+\omega(1-\cos\theta)}{m}
+\frac{m}{m+\omega(1-\cos\theta)}
+\cos^2\theta-1
\right)
\end{equation}

Here is a plot of the cross section formula for $\omega=m$.

[image]

This is the probability density for Compton scattering.

\begin{equation}
f(\theta)\propto\left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\right)\sin\theta
\end{equation}

Here is a plot of $f(\theta)$ for $\omega=m$.

[image]

Because of the $\sin\theta$ factor in $f(\theta)$, the probability is small for angular intervals near $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$. For example

\begin{equation}
P(0^\circ\le\theta\le5^\circ)=0.0065
\end{equation}

compared to

\begin{equation}
P(35^\circ\le\theta\le40^\circ)=0.0528
\end{equation}

See the following link for a complete derivation of the probability density $f(\theta)$.

http://www.eigenmath.org/compton-scattering.pdf